# Submitting POST request from Cordova app to Google App Engine not reaching server at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, google-app-engine, cordova

I have a Cordova app (HTML/Javascript-files wrapped into iOS WebView) which is exhibiting some weird behaviour.

I submit forms to  a python-script on Google App Engine, and this works sometimes, but not all the time. When the form includes base64 encodes images, it is more likely that the it won't work.

What I mean with not working is that it doesn't reach the server at all. The server logs show that no request to the "/submit"-handler has been made. This is only for the iOS-version of the app. The Android-version works fine with the same code.

My biggest suspicions was the cross-domain issue. Here's my jQuery code which sends the form:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://myapp.appspot.com/submit",
    data: submittedEntryString,
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);
    console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

However I have added the header to my response. I suppose this is the correct way to do it(?)

```
self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
self.write("form submitted! form id is: " + str(s.form_id))
```

Any ideas what would cause this kind of behaviour?

Comment: you need to include the response headers at the server as well. i.e the server should also respond with the correct headers. CORS should be enabled both on the client as well as the server.

Comment: @frank I included my server side code at the end of my post. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross domain issue only occurs when you test your app code on PC browser after code below is inserted into config.xml.

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Anyway, your code seems to be correct. 
My suggestion is that you could try the steps below.

(1) Not post your image and check if text data could be posted well.

(2) Use phonegap "Filetransfer" to post data includes images.

Comment: 1. Have tested posting just text and that works sometimes. Not always though. 2. Filetransfer looks really interesting. Will definitely look into it. Thanks!